# Using grep to recursively search a directory for a pattern while excluding another pattern

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I want to search for a pattern in all files within a directory.
I know that this can be achieved using

```
grep -r "<pattern1>"
```

But I want to display all lines amongst all files that have pattern1 and does not have a second pattern say pattern2.

For example:

```
grep -r "chrome"
```

The above command prints all line that have the word "chrome". But i would like to print only those lines that have chrome but do not contain "chrome.storage.sync".

Comment: An example has been added. @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pipe to filter out the  lines as

```
grep "chrome" inputFile | grep -v "chrome\.storage\.sync"
```

From man page

```
   -v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

**Test**

```
$ cat test
chrome
chrome chrome.storage.sync

$ grep "chrome" test | grep -v "chrome\.storage\.sync"
chrome
```

Comment: i think you need to escape the dots.

Answer (score 2):

If your grep support `P` then you could use the below regex based grep command.

```
grep -Pr '^(?=.*chrome)(?!.*chrome\.storage\.sync)'
```

**Regular Expression:**

```
^                        the beginning of the string
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                           times)
  chrome                   'chrome'
)                        end of look-ahead
(?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                           times)
  chrome                   'chrome'
  \.                       '.'
  storage                  'storage'
  \.                       '.'
  sync                     'sync'
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Much shorter form,

```
grep -Pr 'chrome(?!\.storage\.sync)'
```

`(?!\.storage\.sync)` Negative lookahead asserts that the string following the match would be any but not of `.storage.sync`

Comment: `grep -Pr 'chrome(?!\.storage\.sync)'` would be shorter

Comment: Why isn't the regex simply `chrome(?!\.storage\.sync)` ?

Comment: Be aware that the short regex will match lines that contain (e.g.) `chrome.chrome.storage.sync`, unlike the long regex or the `grep -v` approach in the accepted answer.